# How to Message me if Soup can't find section on Website ? per discord or idk

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, send

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://shop.travisscott.com/password').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


Article = soup.find('p')

print(Article.prettify())
```

Comment: Can you let us know a bit more context of what have done as well as what your overall objective is? Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Comment: I try to run a script 24/7 to see if something change on the website and if this happened to receive a message per Discord or Idk maybe the Community know a faster or better way. (: